# Rhino Service Bus via rhino.queues - error sending messages

Tags: c#, message-queue, rhino-servicebus

Im getting an error when I try to send a message from a Test Project, 
This is the exception message

> Could not find a message owner for C2C.RhinoUtil.EventServiceBus
>      at
>   Rhino.ServiceBus.Impl.MessageOwnersSelector.GetEndpointForMessageBatch(Object[]
>   messages)    at Rhino.ServiceBus.Impl.DefaultServiceBus.Send(Object[]
>   messages)    at
>   C2C.Infraestructura.Aspect.EventDispatcherAspect.Intercept(IInvocation
>   invocation) in
>   f:\Proyectos\C2C\Desarrollo\Trunk\C2C.Infraestructura\Aspect\EventDispatcherAspect.cs:line
>   44

this is my config of my test app.config (this work like a client that send messages to a central application)

```
<rhino.esb>
<bus threadCount="1" numberOfRetries="5" endpoint="rhino.queues://localhost:50002/RhinoServiceBusTest" name="client" />
<messages>
  <add name="messagges" endpoint="rhino.queues://localhost:50001/RhinoServiceBusBackend" />
</messages>
<assemblies>
  <add assembly="Rhino.ServiceBus.RhinoQueues" />
</assemblies>
```

this is my backend config

```
<rhino.esb>
<bus threadCount="1" numberOfRetries="5" endpoint="rhino.queues://localhost:50001/RhinoServiceBusBackend" name="backend" />    
<assemblies>
  <add assembly="Rhino.ServiceBus.RhinoQueues" />
</assemblies>
```

and this is part of my code to send a message

```
QueueUtil.PrepareQueue("client");

var host = new DefaultHost();
host.Start<ClientBootStrapper>();

//Console.WriteLine("Client 1: Hit enter to send message");
//Console.ReadLine();

var bus = host.Bus as IServiceBus;

var eventSB = new EventServiceBus();
eventSB.Nombre = methodName;
eventSB.Service = invocation.TargetType.FullName;
eventSB.Data = (arguments as BusinessEntity).UnProxy(); ;

try
{
    bus.Send(eventSB);
}
catch (Exception)
{

    throw;
}
```

Basically Im intercepting all the transactions and try to notify to another backend application, but

From my test method I create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the app.config of the test project, you have to set the bus name like the entity namespace, like this

```
<messages>
  <add name="C2C.RhinoUtil" endpoint="rhino.queues://localhost:50001/RhinoServiceBusBackend" />
</messages>
```

where "C2C.RhinoUtil" is the namespace of my class "EventServiceBus" that is sent in the message